# bit-bucket - download file for specific commit

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-commit, git-clone

I can get the project through git clone command, but is there any way where i get my file for my previous-specific commit or can pull my file for previous-specific commit. 
please , suggest me !

Comment: ehm, `git checkout <required-commit>` ? or `git log` to observe the list of commits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation mentions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/src-resources-296095214.html#srcResources-GETrawcontentofanindividualfile)

```
https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/repositories/{accountname}/{repo_slug}/raw/{revision}/{path}
```

For instance ([`jespern/django-piston/raw/tip/piston/utils.py`](https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/jespern/django-piston/raw/tip/piston/utils.py)):

```
curl https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/jespern/django-piston/raw/tip/piston/utils.py
```

If you want a different `{revision}`, like

- the [one from the `0.2.2-maint` branch](https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/jespern/django-piston/raw/0.2.2-maint/piston/utils.py):

  ```
  curl https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/jespern/django-piston/raw/0.2.2-maint/piston/utils.py
  ```
- the [one from a specific commit fde50de72c4b](https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/jespern/django-piston/raw/fde50de72c4b/piston/utils.py):

  ```
  curl https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/jespern/django-piston/raw/fde50de72c4b/piston/utils.py
  ```

Comment: please tell me about revision !